# Accessing ruby application on Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: ruby, azure, redmine

I am trying to install project management application called [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) on Windows Azure Virtual Machine and access it from internet. Redmine is based on Ruby and is using a database so I also had to install them too. Actually I managed to install everything and when I connect to virtual machine by Remote Desktop I can access Redmine there by typing localhost/redmine in browser. The question is what should I do now to access it from outside? (for example home pc or anybody in internet). My virtual machine has got an address like myapp.cloudapp.com but there is no way I can access redmine by typing myapp.cloudapp.com/redmine or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't exactly speak for Azure as I haven't used it, but there should be a way to forward port 80 through to your VM.  You should also make sure IIS is setup to listen on 0.0.0.0:80 and not 127.0.0.1:80

Edit: Usually port forwarding is setup in the control panel for a cloud provider, so I would start by checking whatever interface Azure gives you to configure your VM.

Comment: Actually all I had to do was to open ports on BOTH virtual machine firewall and on management page in endpoints. In my case those were 80, 3000 (ruby), 8080 (tomcat) and 3306 (mysql)